# how to check a string contains newline or not in salesforce formulae

Tags: formula

2335 N. Michigan Avenue, Suite 1500
Chicago, IL 60601, USA

for this above string how to check this string contains a newline or not?

Comment: Please take some time to read [ask] and [help/on-topic], and take the SFSE [tour]. Continuing to post questions that don't show your work and research, and which are received negatively by the community, may result in further posts being declined.

Answer (score 2):

It cannot be done with formula. You could use something like `Contains(asdf__c, '\n')`, but line breaks are saved only in long text area fields and those cannot be referenced in formula. Simple text field will remove all line breaks.